# How to give root access to apps that don't request it?

Tags: root-access, system, terminal, protected-apps

I've been using the app SystemPanel for some time now to archive my Android apps.  It works great, but it cannot archive apps that have been installed under /data/app-private, because this directory is not world-readable.  I recently rooted my HTC Incredible and have Superuser running on it, so I would like to give root access to SystemPanel, but it doesn't request it.  Is there a way to have Superuser grant root access to an app that does not request it?  Alternatively, is there any other way (e.g. from the terminal) to grant root access to an arbitrary app?

Thanks!

P.S. I know that now I can change the permissions on /data/app-private to make it accessible to SystemPanel, but I think granting root access to SystemPanel would be the safer strategy.

Comment: This duplicate question has good answers: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26046/how-to-add-root-permission-to-some-app-by-myself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The application needs to request root access. If it is not developed to use root access, it cannot be given the root access. in  order for it to work how you want it, you may have to change the permissions to /data/app-private, like you mentioned.