# Can you grant superuser privileges to an application?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, supersu

I was wondering wether it is possible since ES File Explorer has the root explorer option,  which I need to see where Termux got installed/from where it's running to be able to navigate (though it seems that I can't).

So, is there a way to grant just it such privileges with adb,  or  at least a permission for viewing such files?

Answer (score 1):

- Your device needs to be rooted first
- You can only grant SU permissions when the application asks for it in a rooted environment. Forcing the app to ask for permissions is not trivial or likely to succeed . For details, see related question linked below
- If you are not rooted, you can't bestow super user privileges to any app

Related [How to add root permission to some app by myself?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26046/how-to-add-root-permission-to-some-app-by-myself)