# Mi mover - why not transfer apps completely?

Tags: file-transfer, xiaomi

I've recently proceeded with setting up new Xiaomi device and used Mi Mover to try to copy from older Xiaomi device. The app said "copying apps, some apps it cannot copy but e.g. Telegram, WhatsApp were ticked as to be copied". After completion app asked to rate it.

I wanted to check results before rating and only media from WhatsApp, telegram were copied. Why can't app of phone manufacturer take care of installing apps on new phone and transfer all user data? I guess Xiaomi can provide its' app with root privileges etc. I have not been able to find answer via googling.

Comment: Which version of Android? //Deleted your PS portion since this is Android specific site. That may be an appropriate question on site dealing with Apple

Comment: Android provides a hardware backed key store that does not allow extraction of key as a protection measure. Apps that depend on this key store and e.g. use a key from this key store to encrypt their user data can not be backuped on file-level even if you have access to the files (e.g. on a rooted devices).

Answer (score 2):

From [MI Mover review](https://xiaomireview.com/mi-mover-can-transfer-your-system-settings-files-and-apps-wirelessly-17-30gb-in-30-mins/)

> **APPS THAT CAN BE TRANSFERRED USING MI MOVER**
>
> > The Mi Mover can transfer system apps and third party apps these apps are mostly from Xiaomi and games that doesn’t need personal data.

> **APPS THAT CAN NOT BE TRANSFERRED USING MI MOVER**
>
> > However, Mi Mover **cannot transfer apps that have personal data**. For example Facebook, Shopee, and Lazada. These apps contains our personal data and Mi Mover doesn’t have a **permission** to transfer these apps’ system settings and data.

(Emphasis supplied)

An app can't be granted root privileges unless the device is rooted (See [Can you grant superuser privileges to an application?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/179541/131553))

Even on rooted devices, you may need extra tricks to  transfer WhatsApp data whereas other apps data can be backed up and restored.

From app developer of [SwiftBackup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.swiftapps.swiftbackup)

> Media part is for the app's media directory at `[InternalStorage/Android/media/[package_name]/`.

> Very few apps use this directory. On Android 11+, WhatsApp uses this directory to store all its media that was previously stored at `InternalStorage/WhatsApp/ folder` on Android 10 and below.

Comment: Thanx, are there any tools (preferably not using Windows) to transfer all (data, apps with settings and user data, accounts, android settings - wifi passwords, etc. i.e. all a user can think of) from one phone to new one w/out root? With root?

Comment: You quoted a site "by Mi fan". Aren't there any official info from Xiaomi on the app? Or maybe Mover is not official app at all ...

Comment: Samsung smart switch does all of the on a brand new device without rooting. How so?

Comment: @th3pirat3, Samsung Smart Switch does not move app data:
"Smart Switch mobile does not support application data backup or restore. Smart Switch only backs up the application on its list."
https://www.samsung.com/za/support/mobile-devices/does-smart-switch-backup-restore-data-from-an-application-like-game-data-or-chatting-log/